# How to fix jquery site redirect based on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say a customer wants to access their webmail by visiting our website. A form would be displayed, when they enter in their domain and click 'login' they would automatically be redirected to [domain]/webmail.

This is for a new WordPress site running MySQL 5, PHP 7.1. I've tried removing the form tags in the hopes that this might be the root cause of the issue. However, the issue continues to persist. When they type in their domain.

I can confirm the form tags aren't needed to be used as I have the working script but when attempting to integrate we experience bugs.

When implementing form tags the user is redirected but to the same page but with /? query on the end.

Not Working Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2> Form</h2>

<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <div class="form-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
<form>

    <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control webmail-input" placeholder="Your domain name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn webmail-btn">Webmail Login</button>
        </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </div>
    </form>
</div>

  <script>
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}





jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function stripDomainTotally(the_domain) {
        //remove www http https
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('https://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('http://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('www.','');
        return the_domain;
    }

    function getWebmail(domain){
        var strip_domain = stripDomainTotally(domain);
        if(strip_domain != ""){
            window.location.href = "https://"+strip_domain+"/webmail";
        }
    }

    $('.webmail-click').click(function () {
        if($('.webmail-drop').css('display') == 'none'){
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeIn("fast");
        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
    $('.webmail-input').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var domain = $('.webmail-input').val();
            getWebmail(domain);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.webmail-btn').click(function () {
        var domain = $('.webmail-input').val();
        getWebmail(domain);
    });

    $(document).on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-drop *, .webmail-drop')){

        }else if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-click *, .webmail-click')){

        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Working Code:

```
<div class="webmail-drop">

        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control webmail-input" placeholder="Your domain name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="webmail-btn">Webmail Login</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function stripDomainTotally(the_domain) {
        //remove www http https
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('https://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('http://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('www.','');
        return the_domain;
    }

    function getWebmail(domain){
        var strip_domain = stripDomainTotally(domain);
        if(strip_domain != ""){
            window.location.href = "https://"+strip_domain+"/webmail";
        }
    }

    $('.webmail-click').click(function () {
        if($('.webmail-drop').css('display') == 'none'){
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeIn("fast");
        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
    $('.webmail-input').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var domain = $('.webmail-input').val();
            getWebmail(domain);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.webmail-btn').click(function () {
        var domain = $('.webmail-input').val();
        getWebmail(domain);
    });

    $(document).on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-drop *, .webmail-drop')){

        }else if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-click *, .webmail-click')){

        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Page is refreshed with the end query on the URL. For example [current page/domain]/?

When the user clicks the button and have entered their domain they should be redirected to their domain/webmail.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:** user redirected to `samepage/?` because this is the form default redirect .. you can check this by add `action = "anypage.php"` to the form .

- To avoid the form's default redirect you need one of `e.preventDefault();` as shown in the code below OR `return false;` at the end of the click event
- Also no need for `keyup` event with <kbd>Enter</kbd> check .. just add `type="submit"` to `webmail-btn` button and it will do the job for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2> Form</h2>

<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <div class="form-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
<form>

    <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control webmail-input" placeholder="Your domain name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn webmail-btn">Webmail Login</button>
        </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}





jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function stripDomainTotally(the_domain) {
        //remove www http https
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('https://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('http://','');
        the_domain = the_domain.replace('www.','');
        return the_domain;
    }

    function getWebmail(domain){
        var strip_domain = stripDomainTotally(domain);
        if(strip_domain != ""){
            console.log("https://"+strip_domain+"/webmail");
            //window.location.href = "https://"+strip_domain+"/webmail";
        }
    }

    $('.webmail-click').click(function () {
        if($('.webmail-drop').css('display') == 'none'){
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeIn("fast");
        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
    
    $('.webmail-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var domain = $('.webmail-input').val();
        getWebmail(domain);
    });

    $(document).on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-drop *, .webmail-drop')){

        }else if ($(event.target).is('.webmail-click *, .webmail-click')){

        }else{
            $('.webmail-drop').fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mohammed, thanks for your advice. Although, the issue continued to persist even with those changes. I've removed the <form> tags to make it appear near identical to the working code. However, even after the removal of change it continues to not work. I'm under the impression it may have something to do with the JQuery?

Comment: While it works in my answer snippet @user3672905 I can't guess why its not working in your site unless it gives you an error .So check the console for errors.. And please explain well what do you mean with *continues to not work* .. you need first to prevent the `form` from default redirect is that happened?